# What did Others do to Walt?

Tags: lost

In *Lost* Others are known to take children, but as later revealed, Alex was only taken because Ben was sent to kill Rousseau and couldn't kill a child.

Later the kidnap Walt who claimed Others did some experiments on him, and they later say that "we received more from Walt than we expected".

What is it they're talking about?

Comment: As far as I could tell, the Walt storyline was never resolved, mainly because the actor actually grew up.

Comment: I think Walt and especially Michael were irksome characters for the audience, so they were simply disappeared, as killing a child felt too hard for that series.